# CUDA In-place Transpose Error

Tags: cuda, transpose, in-place

I'm implementing a CUDA program for transposing an image. I created 2 kernels. The first kernel does out of place transposition and works perfectly for any image size.

Then I created a kernel for in-place transposition of square images. However, the output is incorrect. The lower triangle of the image is transposed but the upper triangle remains the same. The resulting image has a stairs like pattern in the diagonal and the size of each step of the stairs is equal to the 2D block size which I used for my kernel.

## Out-of-Place Kernel:

**Works perfectly for any image size if src and dst are different.**

```
template<typename T, int blockSize>
__global__ void kernel_transpose(T* src, T* dst, int width, int height, int srcPitch, int dstPitch)
{
    __shared__ T block[blockSize][blockSize];

    int col = blockIdx.x * blockSize + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockSize + threadIdx.y;

    if((col < width) && (row < height))
    {
        int tid_in = row * srcPitch + col;
        block[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = src[tid_in];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    col = blockIdx.y * blockSize + threadIdx.x;
    row = blockIdx.x * blockSize + threadIdx.y;

    if((col < height) && (row < width))
    {
        int tid_out = row * dstPitch + col;
        dst[tid_out] = block[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];
    }
}
```

## In-Place Kernel:

```
template<typename T, int blockSize>
__global__ void kernel_transpose_inplace(T* srcDst, int width, int pitch)
{
    __shared__ T block[blockSize][blockSize];

    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int tid_in = row * pitch + col;
    int tid_out = col * pitch + row;

    if((row < width) && (col < width))
        block[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = srcDst[tid_in];

    __threadfence();

    if((row < width) && (col < width))
        srcDst[tid_out] = block[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y];
}
```

## Wrapper Function:

```
int transpose_8u_c1(unsigned char* pSrcDst, int width,int pitch)
{
    //pSrcDst is allocated using cudaMallocPitch

    dim3 block(16,16);
    dim3 grid;
    grid.x = (width + block.x - 1)/block.x;
    grid.y = (width + block.y - 1)/block.y;

    kernel_transpose_inplace<unsigned char,16><<<grid,block>>>(pSrcDst,width,pitch);

    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    return 1;
}
```

## Sample Input & Wrong Output:

[image] [image]

I know this problem has something to do with the logic of **in-place** transpose. This is because my out of place transpose kernel which is working perfectly for different source and destination, also gives the same wrong result if I pass it a single pointer for source and destination.

What am I doing wrong? Help me in correcting the In-place kernel.

Comment: Could you add the pictures, before, after-correct, and after-wrong. It helps with visualization of the problem. Also if you could include the code for the out-of-place kernel

Comment: @ks6g10... Added both. Well... Isn't it obvious what is **after-correct**?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your in-place kernel is overwriting data in the image that will be subsequently picked up by another thread to use for its transpose operation.  So *for a square image*, you should buffer the destination data before overwriting  it, then place the destination data in it's proper transposed location.  Since we're doing effectively 2 copies per thread using this method, there's only a need to use half as many threads.  Something like this should work:

```
template<typename T, int blockSize>
__global__ void kernel_transpose_inplace(T* srcDst, int width, int pitch)
{

    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int tid_in = row * pitch + col;
    int tid_out = col * pitch + row;

    if((row < width) && (col < width) && (row<col)) {

        T temp = srcDst[tid_out];

        srcDst[tid_out] = srcDst[tid_in];
        srcDst[tid_in] = temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It really solved the problem. But one thing is confusing? Haven't I already buffered the data in shared memory? To make sure that all the threads have buffered the data, I used `threadfence()`.

Comment: I thought you might have questions about `__threadfence()`  It is a kind of barrier but it is not a device-wide barrier.  It is only a barrier for the particular thread.  If it acted as a barrier for all threads simultaneously, then your method might work.  But there is no global barrier in CUDA, other than via kernel launch/exit.  You may wish to read the [description](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions).  As you had it, it only guaranteed that the write to shared memory was visible to other threads *in the block* before execution continued.

Comment: Yes I read the description of `__threadfence()` and from the second point in its documentation, I always thought it was like `__syncthreads()` for the whole grid.

Comment: The key phrase is "made by the calling thread".  This means it only blocks execution of whatever thread it is in, and it only blocks execution until those two visibility conditions are met.  It's quite a bit different than `__syncthreads()`, and as I stated, there is no global sync mechanism in CUDA.  Unlike `__syncthreads()` it does *not* force multiple threads to reach the barrier before any thread execution can continue.

Comment: Hi folks, this doesn't seem to work for non-square matrices. Why would this be the case?

Comment: A square matrix has a diagonal that splits the image in half.  The in-place approach in the question and my answer both make use of this.  For non-square matrices, I believe the original out-of-place transpose listed in the question would probably work.  It should be fairly obvious that the posted answer requires a square matrix since both row and column indices are tested against the same dimension/parameter (`width`).