# In-Place CUDA Kernel for Rectangular Matrix Transpose

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, transpose

I have perused around for a while, but was unable to find a proper answer for this:

> Is there an implementation for in-place diagonal matrix transpose in CUDA?

I am aware of **cublas geam**, but that requires creating another matrix. I tried a naive implementation from: [CUDA In-place Transpose Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174876/cuda-in-place-transpose-error)

However, that only works for square matrices. Can someone explain to me why exactly this logic does not work for diagonal matrices? The 'naive' approach for transposition works though, however it is not in place.

Comment: Are your diagonal matrices square, or rectangular `m x n` matrices, `m != n` ? I assume it is the latter since square diagonal matrices are symmetric and thus their own transpose. Can you point to a paper defining a standard algorithm or a function from a CPU-based reference library that performs transposition of rectangular diagonal matrices?

Comment: If you really want to do it in-place with O(1) space, check out this implementation: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=12339553 (the 4th answer by the guy named 111). But this is probably not a good impl for CUDA. Have also you checked this one:  https://research.nvidia.com/publication/decomposition-place-matrix-transposition

Comment: njuffa : they are rectangular where m != n. I have tried the naive transpose implementation which can be reviewed here: https://github.com/parallel-forall/code-samples/blob/master/series/cuda-cpp/transpose/transpose.cu

Comment: Thanks asm . I will try to implement the logic in that paper.

Comment: @bge0: I add the link to the paper to the answer so that other people can find it easily. You can accept it if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around for a while I found the following github page which does have code related to the nvidia research paper for an in-place transpose:

https://github.com/BryanCatanzaro/inplace

This seems to be the correct way to solve this question.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following paper: [A Decomposition for In-place Matrix Transposition](https://research.nvidia.com/publication/decomposition-place-matrix-transposition)

Sequential algorithm for in-place matrix transpose is as follows (> O(n*m) running time):

```
// in:  n rows; m cols
// out: n cols; m rows
void matrix_transpose(int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j;
    for(int k = 0; k < n*m; k++) {
        int idx = k;
        do { // calculate index in the original array
            idx = (idx % n) * m + (idx / n);
        } while(idx < k); // make sure we don't swap elements twice
        std::swap(a[k], a[idx]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ASM, thanks for the link to the paper. This is the right solution, however the cpu code is not relevant to the question.